# how to set my own paramers and config symfony2

Tags: symfony, parameters

i want to use my own parametes.ini file in my symfony project.
does anyone know about that?
I know this file

```
#app/config/parameters.ini
```

but I wnat to include my own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/config/config.yml` there are lines:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

Just add your file there.

```
imports:
    ...
    - { resource: your_custom_file.yml }
```

Your custom file should be located in `app/config` directory. In case if you would like to include file from Bundle - you can import it in next way:

```
imports:
    ...
    - { resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/your_custom_file.yml" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `parameters.ini` file should be ignored in a VCS. Instead, copy it to `parameters.ini.dist` and put it under a VCS control. Then, when developing, each developer copies `parameters.ini.dist` to `parameters.ini` and changes parameters to her own needs.