# symfony2 how do you create your own custom yml file to share globally?

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml

I am looking to create my own yml file to store some global settings and vars that I can re-use across my project.  I have searched on here and found another answer however it does not work for me

[Set own parameters in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127927/how-to-set-my-own-paramers-and-config-symfony2)

I'm looking to add the **report_settings.yml** file so that its automatically loaded across my project.

this is what I have so far based

```
#app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: report_settings.yml }

 .. rest of config file --
```

and the file im trying to include looks like this

```
#report_settings.yml
something:
    something1: "test"
```

It returns the following error

```
FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/var/www/pcPortal/app/config/report_settings.yml" from "/var/www/pcPortal/app/config/config.yml".
```

and

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "something" (in /var/www/pcPortal/app/config/report_settings.yml). Looked for namespace "something", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_aop", "jms_di_extra", "jms_security_extra", "sj_query", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
```

From reading the error messages it looks like I have missed something out?  Do I need to add some kind of extension?

Comment: My question might be usefull - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482622/creating-a-configuration-file-in-symfony2/32502618#32502618

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest would be to put your config into the parameters section like:

```
#report_settings.yml
parameters:
    something.something1: "test"
```

You could also process the config with your own extension see http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions

Comment: this worked.  to get the var I just need to do $this->container->getParameter('something.test')

Comment: how do I call the $this->container->getParameter() from inside an entity?

Comment: You will have to pass the values needed to the entity like `$report = new Report($this->container->getParameter('something.test'))` or via setter. You could also configure your Report as a service in the container.

Comment: ahh the idea being the yml file was that I could have some shared easily configurable settings across the reports(there are going to be quite a few) .  Passing the values in will mean I keep repeating it and make the code less readable.  What do you mean by set it as a service in the container?

Comment: If you are creating a report generator you could configure it in the service container and configure it there. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container And then just use it in your controller with `$this->container->get('reportGenerator')`