# Creating configurations in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

For a few hours now I've been struggling to do the most simple thing you can imagine and it just won't work. I've read tons of stackoverflow questions, read the complete Symfony documentation on configuration files and with every article or other piece of information I read, it gets harder and harder to understand.

#### Details

I've created my own Bundle. Lets call it `HappyBundle`. I've put this Bundle in my company's folder. So naturally I've got `CompanyHappyBundle`.

I want to make a configuration file specifically for this bundle as I want it to be reusable.

As I test i created the following:

```
# src/Company/HappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
company_happy:
    import:
        path: /tmp
```

Now, what I want is to be able to use this value in my Controller. I just don't know how. It throws me the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "company_happy" (in /home/user/symfony/src/Company/HappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml).

Looked for namespace "company_happy", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in /home/user/symfony/src/Company/HappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml (which is being imported from "/home/user/symfony/app/config/config.yml").
```

#### Update

In the config.yml I added the following:

```
#app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: "@CompanyHappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" }
```

I've also made a Configuration class because I read somewhere this was required. I really do think this is alot of work to make just one config file.

```
namespace Company\HappyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company_happy');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->arrayNode('import')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('attachments_path')->defaultValue('/tmp')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('method')->defaultValue('ALL')->end()
                    ->booleanNode('move_mail')->defaultValue(true)->end()
                    ->booleanNode('mark_read')->defaultValue(true)->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

What I am actually looking for are the steps and requirements needed to get this working. The thing with symfony is that it has a million ways to do this. The documentation doesn't just give a workflow.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Is your bundle called Happy or CompanyHappy?.  By default, S2 uses the name for configuration.  Any slight deviations will cause problems.  Start by verifying your DI:Extension class is being loaded.

Comment: @Cerad Uhm.. Di:Extension class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved my own issue but not without trouble. I'm not at all pleased with Symfony's configuration system.

#### Step one - Create your config file

Create a file named `config.yml` in `src/<bundle name>/Resources/config/`

```
yourbundle:
    param_one: value_one
    param_two: value_two
    param_three: value_three
    param_four: value_four
    param_five:
        subparam_one: subvalue_one
        subparam_two: subvalue_two
        subparam_three: subvalue_three
        subparam_four: subvalue_four
```

#### Step two - Importing your configuration file

Go to `app/config/config.yml` and add:

```
#app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" }
```

#### Step three - Create a configuration class

Create a file named `Configuration.php` in `src/<bundle name>/DependencyInjection/`

```
namespace YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('yourbundle');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('param_one')->defaultValue('value_one')->end()
                ->scalarNode('param_two')->defaultValue('value_two')->end()
                ->scalarNode('param_three')->defaultValue('value_three')->end()
                ->scalarNode('param_four')->defaultValue('value_four')->end()
                ->arrayNode('param_five')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('subparam_one')->defaultValue('subvalue_one')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('subparam_two')->defaultValue('subvalue_two')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('subparam_three')->defaultValue('subvalue_three')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('subparam_four')->defaultValue('subvalue_four')->end()
                    ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

#### Step four - Creating an extension

Last but not least, you'll have to create an extension. Create a file `<yourbundle>Extension.php` in `src/<your bundle>/DependencyInjection/`

```
namespace YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class YourbundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerBuilder
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->parseNode('yourbundle.'.$key, $value);
        }

        $container->setParameter('yourbundle', $config);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed  $value
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function parseNode($name, $value)
    {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $this->set($name, $value);

            return;
        }
        if (is_integer($value)) {
            $this->set($name, $value);

            return;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $newKey => $newValue) {
                $this->parseNode($name.'.'.$newKey, $newValue);
            }

            return;
        }
        if (is_bool($value)) {
            $this->set($name, $value);

            return;
        }
        throw new \Exception(gettype($value).' not supported');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed  $value
     */
    protected function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->container->setParameter($key, $value);
    }
}
```

All these steps are required just to be able to call a configuration parameter specific for your bundle.

If any of you know any way to do this easier, feel free to post an answer or comment.

Comment: After playing around with this I found that `$ php app/console generate:bundle` created _most_ of the code you provided. Where I only needed to add the structure of my specific bundle's config to `configuration.php` and expose the config as a parameter in `<bundle>Extension.php`.

Comment: It's great that you got it working but I don't understand your unhappiness.  In your question you indicated that you had thoroughly read all the relevant sections of the documentation.  All of the above steps are clearly listed.  And of course, as @HPierce indicates, generate:bundle takes care of most of the busy work.  Of course in most cases you can just declare a couple of parameters and be done with it.

Comment: @Cerad I found this workflow in scrambled parts throughout the documentation. There should be a single page that explains how to do this. Without giving any extra unneccasary formation.

Comment: It is one of the more complicated (and powerful) aspects of the framework but I think they did a good job explaining it with: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html.

Answer (score 3):

A few notices:

In config.yml, you are trying to define `import` as array. It seems like symfony doesn't allow creating array elements in the root of your config, meaning that you have to nest arrays deeper down the tree. So you can not do:

```
company_happy:
    import:
        path: /tmp
    another_import:
        ...
```

I am not sure this is exactly what you were trying to do, but you defined `import` as array, which makes me assume so.

On the other hand, you can do:

```
company_happy:
    imports:
        import:
            path: /tmp
        another_import:
            ...
```

Regarding *no extension able to load the configuration* error: Make sure your extension file is following naming convetions.It should be called `CompanyHappyExtension.php` with `CompanyHappyExtension` class defined inside.

I have created a sample [CompanyHappyBundle](https://github.com/systemist/CompanyHappyBundle) bundle which is working fine on Symofny 3 (probably works on S2 as well). Feel free to clone/download it :)

The services.yml file is an added bonus, as you will most likely need it anyway.

**src/Company/Bundle/HappyBundle/CompanyHappyBundle.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\HappyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class CompanyHappyBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```

**src/Company/Bundle/HappyBundle/DependencyInjection/CompanyHappyExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\HappyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface;


class CompanyHappyExtension extends Extension implements ExtensionInterface
{


    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $options = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        // Do something with your options here
    }


}
```

**src/Company/Bundle/HappyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

```
<?

namespace Company\Bundle\HappyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company_happy');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('imports')
                    ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('path')->defaultValue('/tmp')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('method')->defaultValue('ALL')->end()
                        ->booleanNode('move_mail')->defaultValue(true)->end()
                        ->booleanNode('mark_read')->defaultValue(true)->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**src/Company/Bundle/HappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml**

```
company_happy:
    imports:
        import:
            path: /tmp
```

**src/Company/Bundle/HappyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
# Define your services here
services:
```

Comment: The CompanyHappy bundle doesnt really provide much value over the original Symfony documentation. It is not a full wiring of the Bundle included. I have indeed all the files and config in place as discussed in this post but I am still stuck with a no Extension error. This is most likely due to the AppKernel but I am still unable to find documentation to suggest this and where to fix. See the error when i run the code with Behat - https://gist.github.com/bizmate/82b4694d53ac23eac315a032bf41e6a5

Answer (score 1):

you're almost done, you just need to configure your Bundle to use your config parameters, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743384).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information but of course I've added my bundle in the AppKernel.

Comment: @Peter I didn't mean to add your bundle to the AppKernel, but to edit the configuration file of your bundle "Company/HappyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php", and add the your configuration in it.